# Is it possible to compare continuous vs. dichotomous decisions in a meaningful way, that doesn't come down to different kinds of analyses?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, continuous-data

I'm interested in finding out how the factors that contribute to a person's decision change when they are making a continuous vs. a dichotomous choice.

However, I'm concerned that these two types of decisions produce different types of data. Thus, would it be possible to make any conclusions about different decision processes taking place, without the concern that observed differences are just a product of linear vs. logistic regression?

To provide a bit more info, people would be making decisions about stimuli. I would be interested in how properties of the stimuli affect ratings differently than binary choices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new, and I'm not so sure if not being 100% confident with my answer is bad form or unacceptable here.  If it is, my apologies, I will in the future post in cases when I'm 100% sure.

The GLM link is still monotonic, as is the identity link function of the linear regression, so I'm inclined to see this as OK, so I don't see why you couldn't draw some useful conclusion with this analysis.

Just to make sure I understand this, you have these models for the $i$th response

$p(\mbox{binary response}_i   | b_1*x_{1i} + b_2*x_{2i})$    % GLM

$p(\mbox{continuous response}_i | c_1*x_{1i} + c_2*x_{2i})$    % linear regression

$i$th value of the covariates $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$, weights for the linear predictor for binary response GLM are $b_1$ and $b_2$, and those for the continuous response are $c_1$ and $c_2$

As a sanity check, why don't you try thresholding the continuous response, and artificially make it binary (for the sake of verifying that any interesting conclusion isn't due to regression being linear or binary)

$p(\mbox{thrsholded continuous response}_i | t_1*x_{1i} + t_2*x_{2i})$    % GLM

Compare your c's and t's.

Do they still seem follow the same general trend?  ie relative strengths of component of $c_i$ with respect to all other $c$s roughly looks like strength of component $t_i$ wrt to all other $t$s.  Unless there's some strong biological nonlinearity or non-monotonous response, I would guess the c's and t's should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to understand how stimuli affects ratings. So, instead of fitting a logistic regression, did you try univariate analysis on this data.

If you do want to use the logistic regression output, then make sense of the probability values you get. If you have a binary logistic regression, where yes or no are the response variables, see how close the probabilities are to the ends.

Also try using the misclassification rate to see how well the data fits or a contingency table can give you perfect idea